# Can I get Incidents of stackdriver policy using API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I was looking on stackdriver dashboard and I found the following http request:

```
https://app.google.stackdriver.com/api/alerting/violation?project={project-id}&page=0&pageSize=8&policyId={policy-id}
```

But I didn't found any docs about this D:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alerting methods for Stackdriver Monitoring appear in the [the Google Cloud Platform documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/).

There does not seem to be an endpoint to list triggered alerts at the moment.

The best option for now would be to add a [webhook as a notification channel](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks) and store the data in whatever way is easier for you to recover later.

Comment: Notification channels dont seem to report when the incident is solved. only when it is opened. you have any ideia how to get the info if a given incident is solved if not API exists and no notification is triggered?

Comment: Notifications are only the for when the alert is triggered, but do not to identify if the situation is ongoing. To check the current situation of your system, you should use the [Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3). The metrics used to trigger the alerts are the same that can be found on the monitoring API.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed, there is currently no public API for retrieving incidents. Jofre's suggestion is a good one for now. I'd note that we're working on a new incident response tool (https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/building-a-more-reliable-infrastructure-with-new-stackdriver-tools-and-partners) which may satisfy some of your use cases once it's fully released.

Aaron Sher, Stackdriver engineer

Comment: Hi Aaron this still does not seem possible? Either release the API or add support for repeating notifications, thanks.

Comment: Google IRM API has been deprecated :( https://cloud.google.com/incident-response/deprecations