# Can I export "incidents" from StackdriverMonitoring?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to export the results of alerts detected by StackDriverMonitoring.
Currently we are aggregating the alerted emails but it is inefficient.
Is there any way to export to csv file or Bigquery?

I tried the following URL, but it seems this only exports the metrix and not the incident exports.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-metrics-export

Comment: When an alert files, the alert is sent through a channel.   There are a variety of channels (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options) which include WebHooks and Pub/Sub.  Might it be possible to add TWO channels to your alerts.  One that notifies the human via email and the other than publishes the data via Pub/Sub.  You can then run a Cloud Function or Scheduled Job to consumer the messages and stick them into BQ or GCS.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623019/can-i-get-incidents-of-stackdriver-policy-using-api

Comment: Your question caused me to write up an article on the story at Medium ... see:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/warehousing-cloud-monitoring-alerts-b648e3746d9

Comment: Thx! I'll take your article and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to export the incident.
But we'll store the incidents in the Bigquery by adding a pubsub to the alert destination instead.

See Kolban's article.
https://medium.com/google-cloud/warehousing-cloud-monitoring-alerts-b648e3746d9