# Group of GCP open incidents trigger 1 email notification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

We have around 100 alerting policies and each incident triggers an email notification to relevant notification channels. I am looking for a way to send out 1 email notification based on the open incidents in a day. Is this somehow possible in GCP Stackdriver? I couldnt find anything in the documentation. Any help or alternative solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get Incidents of stackdriver policy using API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623019/can-i-get-incidents-of-stackdriver-policy-using-api)

Comment: Not really, I am looking for something like grouping multiple alerts which send out a single email with list of incidents based on these group of alerts